# Bypass "Swipe up to unlock" on Android Lollipop lock screen

Tags: security, 5.0-lollipop, pattern-lock

I recently flashed my Nexus 4 to Android Lollipop using the factory image.

I have set a pattern lock for unlocking the device. But whenever I turn on the phone, I have to click on the little lock icon or swipe upwards to bring up the pattern unlocker dots.In KitKat or earlier versions, those dots would come up as soon as I turn on the phone.

Is there any way to set the pattern dots visible on lock screen by default? I went through all the settings but in vain.

Comment: Nope, but please vote on the tracking issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79889

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, currently there is no setting to turn off the "safety lock" due to the addition of notifications on the lock screen. (Strangely, the lock is still there even if the user chooses not to display any notification)

The best bet to bypass this is to use [Smart Lock's Trusted face](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/20/lollipop-feature-spotlight-smart-lock-brings-trusted-face-mode-that-makes-face-unlock-so-amazing-you-might-actually-use-it/), a new feature in Android 5.0 Lollipop similar to previous face unlock. You can bypass both "safety lock" and "pattern lock" simultaneously by looking at the phone while on the lock screen. I would say there is no downside (as far as my experience goes). If it fails to detect your face, then you just have to swipe up and draw the pattern normally.

How to set up:

- Go to Settings - Security
- Tap "Smart Lock", confirm your current pattern lock
- Tap "Trusted face" and follow the instruction

Comment: Good point, it works. However, I think the face recognition is to slow (using the HTC One), even if I "trained" the face recognition. In most situations I would be faster in sliding up + using my pattern. Therefore I hope Google will fix this by adding the option to disable lock screen but use a pattern, pin, what ever.. Another point is to add trusted places. This works great at home.

Comment: @Michael yeah, I also feel the same. About 'Trusted places', at that time Nexus 4 didn't have this feature yet, only 'Trusted devices' and 'Trusted faces', so I didn't include it since I couldn't test and evaluate it :)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what Andrew T. posted, one can also have

- Trusted location: Phone will not challenge user with the pattern lock
  if the user is present at the location added in this setting. Home
  and Work locations will be present by default, more locations could
  be added.
- Trusted devices: One can add bluetooth devices such as Android wear
  or bluetooth headsets etc. Phone will recognize those devices and
  will bypass pattern unlocker.

Comment: Where does one add a trusted location? The only options I have under smart lock are trusted devices and trusted face.

Comment: You will find it on this link:
http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/18/google-play-services-update-adds-trusted-places-feature-to-lollipops-smart-lock/

Comment: @derobert regarding Trusted Location on Nexus 4 issue: see [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/88263/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT I'm checking for it on a Nexus 5 and Nexus 10. The play services update hasn't hit my devices yet. I presume Google is doing a phased rollout like normal.

Comment: This does not get rid of the pre-lock screen nag screen though.

Answer (score 1):

Official stock Android doesn't support that, but [Cyanogenmod does since September 2015](http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/101254/) in CM 12.1 ROM.

Comment: I have 12.1 and I don't see the option anywhere.