# Trusted places not present under Smart lock in Nexus 5 (Android 5.0 lollipop)

Tags: nexus-5, google-play-services, smart-lock

I have just updated to Lollipop on my Nexus 5 and can't see "Trusted Places". I use "Trusted Device" which works pretty well, but I would like to use "Trusted Places" at work. However, it is not there.

I have looked for the Google Play Services and find the version is still 6.1.88.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nexus 4 Smart Lock Trusted Places is not there!](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88263/nexus-4-smart-lock-trusted-places-is-not-there), except use [the build for Nexus 5 instead](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-6-5-87-1599771-438-apk/).

Comment: Certainly related, but the difference in devices could come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to activate the Trust Agent: Settings -> Security -> Trust Agents -> enable Smart Lock